# How to add page number to the URL

Tags: reactjs, redux, pagination

Could someone please tell me how can I add page number to my url. The component is as follows:

```
/** NPM Packages */
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Spinner, Pagination } from "react-bootstrap";
//import styles from "./App.module.css";

/** Custom Packages */
import List from "../List";
//import fetchCategories from "../../../actions/configuration/category/fetchCategories";
import deleteCategory from "../../../actions/configuration/category/deleteCategory";
import API from "../../../../app/pages/utils/api";

class Category extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mesg: "",
      mesgType: "",
      isLoading: true,
      total: null,
      per_page: null,
      current_page: 1,
      pdata: []
    };
    this.fetchCategoriesAPI = this.fetchCategoriesAPI.bind(this);
  }

  fetchCategoriesAPI = async pno => {
    await API.get("categories?offset=" + (pno.index+1))
      .then(res => this.setState({ pdata: res.data }))
      .then(() => this.props.passToRedux(this.state.pdata))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
      };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const { state } = this.props.location;
    if (state && state.mesg) {
      this.setState({
        mesg: this.props.location.state.mesg,
        mesgType: this.props.location.state.mesgType
      });
      const stateCopy = { ...state };
      delete stateCopy.mesg;
      this.props.history.replace({ state: stateCopy });
    }

    this.closeMesg();
    await this.fetchCategoriesAPI(1);
    this.setState({ isLoading: false });
  };

  onDelete = async id => {
    this.props.removeCategory(id);
    await deleteCategory(id).then(data =>
      this.setState({ mesg: data.msg, mesgType: "success" })
    );
    this.closeMesg();
  };

  closeMesg = () =>
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        this.setState({ mesg: "", mesgType: "" });
      }.bind(this),
      10000
    );

  /** Rendering the Template */
  render() {
    let activePage = this.state.pdata.currPage;
    let items = [];
    let totalPages = Math.ceil(this.state.pdata.totalCount / 10);
    for (let number = 1; number <= totalPages; number++) {
      items.push(
        <Pagination.Item key={number} active={number == activePage}>
          {number}
        </Pagination.Item>
      );
    }

    const paginationBasic = (
      <div>
        <Pagination>
          {items.map((item,index)=>{
            return <p key={index} onClick={() => this.fetchCategoriesAPI({index})}>{item}</p>
          })}
        </Pagination>
        <br />
      </div>
    );

    const { mesg, mesgType, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        {mesg ? (
          <div
            className={"alert alert-" + mesgType + " text-white mb-3"}
            role="alert"
          >
            {mesg}
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        {isLoading ? (
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <h4
              className="panel-body"
              style={{ "text-align": "center", margin: "auto" }}
            >
              Loading&nbsp;
              <Spinner animation="border" role="status" />
            </h4>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <List
              listData={this.props.categories}
              listName="category"
              _handleDelete={this.onDelete.bind(this)}
            />
            {paginationBasic}
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const matchStatestoProps = state => {
  return { categories: state.categories };
};

const dispatchStatestoProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    passToRedux: pload =>
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_CATEGORIES", payload: pload }),
    removeCategory: id => dispatch({ type: "DELETE_CATEGORY", payload: id })
  };
};

export default connect(matchStatestoProps, dispatchStatestoProps)(Category);
```

the route is as follows:

```
 <Route exact path="/categories/:page?" component={Category} />
```

So basically I want the page number to  be displayed in the URL. Also if I change the page number, the data should load the corresponding page. Please help me

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: can you please post the things you have tried and what are the problems you are facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In a class component:

Your router will pass [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) in as a prop. When your component mounts, get `this.props.match.params.page` and load the data accordingly:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    // get the 'page' param out of the router props.
    // default to 0 if not specified.
    const { page  = 0 } = this.props.match.params;

    // it comes in as a string, parse to int
    const p = parseInt(page, 10);

    // do whatever you need to do (load data, etc.)
  }
}
```

### In a function component:

In a function component, you can get the page param via react-router's [useParams hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams):

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyComponent () {
  const { page } = useParams(); // get the 'page' router param
  const p = parseInt(page, 10); // comes in as a string, convert to int

  // do whatever you need to do with it
}
```

If you need prev/next navigation you can deduce those page numbers from the current page.

I made [this quick example](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-haze-5wc8i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that demonstrates how to access and use the route's url parameters via react router's [useParams hook](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) and how to do it via the `match` prop with a class component.

Comment: Can you please write the code for me? I tried something similar but I did not succeed

Comment: See the example I linked to above. It's not doing any data fetching or anything, but it shows how to access the page param coming in from the router.

Answer (score 0):

You can get page number from props like this:

```
const matchStatestoProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { id: ownProps.match.params.id; categories: state.categories };
};
```

In your routes:

```
<Route path="/page/:id" component={Page} />
```