# How to construct dynamic query string in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app which I want to have this query string /contacts?page=${pageNumber}
where page number have to change when I go to the next page, I use newer version of react-router-dom which doesn't have useHistory hook. Now my URL is only http://localhost:3000/.

I have this code:

```
const Contact = (props) => {
let array = Object.values(props);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
const [entry, setEntry] = useState([]);
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
const [isSynchronizedClicked, setIsSynchronizedClicked] = useState(false);

const handlePaging = (params) => {
    setPageNumber(params + 1);
    //navigate(`/contacts?page=${pageNumber}`);
};

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (searchTerm !== '') {
            search();
        }
    }, 500);
}, [searchTerm, search]);

return (
    <>
        <div style={{ height: 630, width: '100%' }}>
            <DataGrid
                id={() => searchTerm === '' ? array.map((contact) => contact.id) : contacts.map((contact) => contact.id)}
                rows={searchTerm === '' ? array : contacts}
                sx={{
                    '.MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle': {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                    },
                    '.MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': {
                        backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3'
                    },
                    '.MuiDataGrid-row': {
                        maxHeight: '51px !important',
                        minHeight: '51px !important'
                    },
                    '.MuiDataGrid-virtualScroller': {
                        overflow: 'hidden'
                    }
                }}
                onPageChange={handlePaging}
                columns={columns}
                pageSize={10}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
                checkboxSelection
                onRowDoubleClick={e => navigateToDetails(e)}
                onSelectionModelChange={e => setEntry(e)}
            />
        </div>
        {isSynchronizedClicked && <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setIsSynchronizedClicked(false)}>
            <div className='synchronize-popup'>
                Do you want to synchronize all contacts ?
                <div className='second-message'>This will take a while.</div>
                <div className='synchronize-popup-buttons-container'>
                    <button className='buttons reject' onClick={() => setIsSynchronizedClicked(false)}>No</button>
                    <button className='buttons approve' onClick={synchronize}>Yes</button>
                </div>

            </div></ClickAwayListener>}
    </>
);
};
```

And this code in App.js:

```
function App() {
return (
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="app">
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<RenderContacts />} />
      <Route path='/details/:id' element={<Details />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
);
}
```

If someone knows how to do that, I'll be grateful.

Comment: This should solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978806/how-to-add-page-number-to-the-url

Answer (score 0):

This is a common gotcha with React `setState`.
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Read the section:
`State Updates May Be Asynchronous`

I assume this is the failure: `pageNumber` likely will not be ready when used.

```
setPageNumber(params + 1);
navigate(`/contacts?page=${pageNumber}`);
```

Instead, just use `params + 1` inside the navigate function.

After navigation, you will want to use `useSearchParams()` (assuming router v6?) to get the updated value.